# How to compress a string using GZip or similar in Dart?

Tags: dart, compression, gzip

I want to compress a string in Dart (in the browser). I tried this:

```
import 'package:archive/archive.dart';

[...]

List<int> stringBytes = UTF8.encode(myString);
List<int> gzipBytes = new GZipEncoder().encode(stringBytes);
String compressedString = UTF8.decode(gzipBytes, allowMalformed: true);
```

Obviously `UTF8.decode` is not intended for this and it doesn't work (file is unreadable).

What is the right way to compress a string in Dart?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? I mean what are you trying to do *with* compressed strings? Can you post more of your code, including writing to a file?

Comment: https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/archive

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Yes, that's what I am using

Comment: Sorry, missed the import. I got the impression you tried it with plain Dart.

Comment: @ArgentiApparatus I encode the string as a data URI and download it, as described here http://stackoverflow.com/a/18197511/1590323 Works perfectly, but I'd like to compress it first. Compressing it manually as gzip decreases size a lot.

Comment: What is the uncompressed data in the file and what do you intend to do with it?

Comment: I have a feeling that you are attempting to save the raw compressed bytes as a file by downloading it from the browser. I think maybe what you actually want to do is create a text file containing your string then put that in a zip *archive* file, and download that.

Comment: @ArgentiApparatus I'm making a webapp. The string is XML that contains the user's work. It's saved with a custom file extension and can later be opened again.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The compressed list of bytes is probably not a valid UTF8 sequence instead you could encode it in base64.

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:archive/archive.dart';

void main() {
  var myString = 'myString';
  var stringBytes = utf8.encode(myString);
  var gzipBytes = GZipEncoder().encode(stringBytes);
  var compressedString = base64.encode(gzipBytes);

  print(compressedString);
}
```

Comment: Or just create a download file from the raw compressed bytes

Comment: @ArgentiApparatus Dart's `Uri.encodeComponent` method, which you need to prepare a file for downloading inside a browser, takes a string and not a list of bytes.

Comment: I see. So if the method you are using to dynamically create a download file *must* deal with a string, you can  BASE64 encode the data bytes as in the above answer, note that it will increase the size of your download somewhat though.

Comment: @ArgentiApparatus Yep, I've noticed that. For one of my test files: Original size: 727 kB, Compressed manually: 236 kB, Compressed with BASE64 encoding: 331 kB. Still a great reduction.

Comment: Just discovered I can use `BASE64URL.encode` instead so I can skip `Uri.encodeComponent`.

Comment: how to decompress it back?

Comment: @maheshmnj `new GZipDecoder().decodeBytes(BASE64.decode(compressedString))`

Answer (score 25):

You can use this function below if you want.

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';

  void _compress(String json) {
    final enCodedJson = utf8.encode(json);
    final gZipJson = gzip.encode(enCodedJson);
    final base64Json = base64.encode(gZipJson);

    final decodeBase64Json = base64.decode(base64Json);
    final decodegZipJson = gzip.decode(decodeBase64Json);
    final originalJson = utf8.decode(decodegZipJson);
    }
```

Comment: This answer is up-to-date, no need to import a third party library.

Comment: Why isn't this the best answer? even though this answer is correct and doesn't require any third party library

Comment: Heads up: this won't likely work for the web because this relies on 'dart:io' which doesn't support the web.

Comment: this should not be the best answer as gzip isn't supported by Flutter Web as of 2023 @noobdev

Answer (score 0):

```
String data=' ';
for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
    data=data+'Hello World!\r\n';
}
var original=utf8.encode(data);
var compressed=gzip.encode(original);
var decompressed=gzip.decode(compressed);
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing an answer. Would you kindly edit your answer to to include an explanation of your code? That will help future readers better understand what is going on, and especially those members of the community who are new to the language and struggling to understand the concepts.