# Flutter Zip & Unzip

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

Hello i want to ask how to zip and unzip become string in flutter :

Example :

```
final int BUFFER_SIZE = 40;
    ByteArrayInputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(compressed);
    GZIPInputStream gis = new GZIPInputStream(is, BUFFER_SIZE);
    StringBuilder string = new StringBuilder();
    byte[] data = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
    int bytesRead;
    while ((bytesRead = gis.read(data)) != -1) { string.append(new String(data, 0, bytesRead)); }
    gis.close();
    is.close();
    return string.toString();
```

Comment: can you clarify the question?

Comment: Could you try to check if [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39735145/how-to-compress-a-string-using-gzip-or-similar-in-dart) could help? Let the community [understand](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) your issue well to improve your chances of getting an answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to compress a string using GZip or similar in Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39735145/how-to-compress-a-string-using-gzip-or-similar-in-dart)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [archive](https://pub.dev/packages/archive) plugin to zip and unzip files.

To unzip:

```dart
// Read the Zip file from disk.
final bytes = File('test.zip').readAsBytesSync();

// Decode the Zip file
final archive = ZipDecoder().decodeBytes(bytes);

// Extract the contents of the Zip archive to disk.
for (final file in archive) {
  final filename = file.name;
  if (file.isFile) {
    final data = file.content as List<int>;
    File('out/' + filename)
      ..createSync(recursive: true)
      ..writeAsBytesSync(data);
  } else {
    Directory('out/' + filename).create(recursive: true);
  }
}
```

To create a zip file:

```dart
// Zip a directory to out.zip using the zipDirectory convenience method
var encoder = ZipFileEncoder();
encoder.zipDirectory(Directory('out'), filename: 'out.zip');
```